# I can hear my GPU when calculating large amounts of data onto it - is that bad?

Tags: memory, gpu

Specifically I am loading about 5GB of data onto a GTX 1060 6GB for training with a neural network, and each time it runs a new batch, I can hear a very brief *whir* noise that lasts about a quarter of a second (it's not a continuous sound it's very short)

Is this a concern? Should I maybe hold back on how much I use the GPU?

ETA:

I looked over my code and realised I actually load all the data in at the beginning and am simply running different segments of it. It's the running of this model that is causing the noise. Specifically, I am using pytorch with a very simplistic 2 layer neural network, and running a tensor of size ~ [200,1000] through the network. This is being repeatedly done and every time my gpu makes a noise.

Comment: I was going to make a joke about loading it in with a forklift, but: what software, how is it being "loaded in" etc. might help make the question (more) answereable. Also: have you established with reasonable certainty that the noise comes from the GPU riser card?

Comment: Are you perhaps referring to “coil whine”?

Comment: could you be hearing the fan ramping up?

Comment: @LPChip I don't think it's the fan because it's only when it's computing something, and is super brief

Comment: @DanielB Maybe? I'm not sure what that would sound like. If that were the case would it be any concern?

Comment: Is the sound repetitive?

Comment: @Virtuality Yes it makes the same noise when it makes a calculation, otherwise it's silent

Comment: Do you know where the sound is coming from? Is it coming from the GPU itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two options:

1. Fan speed increase
2. Coil whine from the 12V to core-power power supplies on the GPU card.

It could also be a mixture of both, the GPU does work, causing extra power to be drawn from the PSU meaning more noise from the PSU, temperature to spike briefly, and fan to briefly spin up slightly due to changing temperature.

Coil whine is a feature of every switch mode power supply on the planet. In a switch mode power supply there is a large circulating current that is flowing backwards and forwards across an inductor. That inductor is a coil of wire surrounding a small magnetic core, and is very similar to a speaker in terms of construction. The only real difference is that a speaker is much larger and the magnetic core is free to move. In an inductor the core is fixed, but the force of the current being passed still causes some level of vibration and noise.

Most of the noise of a power supply will be far outside human audible range, but some harmonics often come down into a range you can hear. This is actually quite difficult to avoid.

[Coil whine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetically_induced_acoustic_noise) is not something you need to worry about, it is a normal feature of modern electronic power supply circuits.

Likewise the fan briefly spinning up a bit while in use is expected and normal.